Does vacuum expectation values of field operators contain all the information of the quantum field theory?
It is a very general question in the field theory context. It means whether anything that we can compute with a canonically quantized Hamilton, can be computed from the generating functional with an arbitrary trajectory on a complex time plane. The specification on arbitrary trajectory is because time-ordered product clearly doesn't contain all the information.

Are you insinuating canonical quantization is not equivalent to the functional integral?

@CosmasZachos No. I mean whether formulating a quantum theory by path integral is as good as starting from the canonical approach since there seems to be missing information. More specifically, path integral in general field theory gives vacuum expectation value of all kinds of operators. For generic amplitudes, there doesn't seems to be a way to restore them from the path integral. In fact, we usually use path integral without knowing what is the Hilbert space exactly.
